# google API consoleのflow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file( ) ,flow.run_local_server()について

Tags: python, google-api

実行しようとしていること：
flow.run_local_server()を使って、アクセストークンを取得しようとしている

エラー文：
エラー 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
（このアプリは Google の OAuth 2.0 ポリシーを遵守していないため、ログインできません。
このアプリのデベロッパーの方は、Google Cloud コンソールでリダイレクト URI を登録してください。）

わからないこと：
エラー文通り、Google Cloud コンソールで、認証情報のなかの、OAuth 2.0 クライアント　IDの編集画面を開き、「承認済みのリダイレクト」の URIリダイレクト URI を「http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login」に設定して、尚且つ、バックエンドのpython(flask)側で
flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('auth.login', _external=True)
の記述も設定しました。
しかし、同じようなエラーが出てしまいます。

何か少しでも改善できる点、わかる点がありましたら教えていただきたく思います。よろしくお願いします。